# spotify artist and album in API lookup

Tags: php, xml, json, api, spotify

I'm making a music lookup service and I'm getting full tracklisting from the Spotify Metadata api. I have the artist name and album name and I'm able to get out the album Sporify ID from just the album name.
Te problem is when there is more album then one with the same name, is it possible to do the request with both artist and album name?
I use this now:

```
$spotify = "http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album?q=$album";
```

I'm using PHP for this and it's on my own server.

Comment: I dont think its possible, you may have to write a secondary script to process the results, based on the artist query....if you know what I mean

Comment: I understand and it would be a lot of work for me, I'm suprised I have come this far with this little knowledge I have haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, of course you can. Prefix the artist name with `artist:` and the album name with `album:` and you're set.

> http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album?q=album:This+Desert+Life+artist:Counting+Crows

Comment: $spotify = "http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/album.xml?q=album:$album+artist:$artist";
Why isn't this working?
I get this error:
Warning: main() [function.main]: Node no longer exists in .../design/album.php on line 16

Comment: The looks like a bug in your own code, not related to Spotify. Our API can't remove nodes in your page.